# FirebaseFaceDetection crash with CameraX

Tags: android, firebase, face-detection

Integrating FirebaseFaceDetetion with CameraX works fine with "setContourMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CONTOURS)". But when i use it with ".setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)"
gives OutOfMemory Exception('java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 518412 byte allocation with 231440 free bytes and 226KB until OOM').

```
public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy, int degrees) {
    if (imageProxy == null || imageProxy.getImage() == null) {
        return;
    }
    Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
    int rotation = degreesToFirebaseRotation(degrees);
    FirebaseVisionImage image =
            FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, rotation);
    FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions configs = new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .build();
    FirebaseVisionFaceDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionFaceDetector(configs);
    detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener(...) });
}
```

I expected to work without any memory issue, but it gets crash after a while.

Answer (score 0):

CameraX API's are in alpha stage ([BackpressureStrategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Builder.html#setBackpressureStrategy(int)),[setImageQueueDepth](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Builder.html#setimagequeuedepth)) : So I have used below workaround:

Workaround:
Analyze only when face detection is not in progress.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    volatile boolean detecting = false;


    private void startCamera() {
//.....
//.....
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(new MainActivity.DirectExecutor(),
                (image, rotationDegrees) -> {
                    //Face Detection analysis start
                    //only after previous detection completed
                    if (!detecting)
                        analyzeImage(image, rotationDegrees);
                });

        CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, imageAnalysis, preview);
    }

    private void analyzeImage(ImageProxy imageProxy, int degrees) {
//...
//...
        detecting = true; //detection true on detection starts
//.. detectio code goes here
        detector.detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces) {
                                if (faces.size() > 0) {
                                    //do come business logics here...
                                    detecting = false;

                                }
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                // Task failed with an exception
                                // ...
                                detecting = false;
                            }
                        });

    }
}
```